# Java ConcurrentModificationException when removing two indexes, current and random one

Tags: java, arrays, loops, exception

I have a list of players.
This list contains players which do not have targets. Targets means that a player is targeted to another player, they two are targets, and should not be in the list.

The purpose of the following loop is to loop through all players, and search for a target, and if the player is not ready yet, it will just call the `tick()` method, which basically ticks down the target search timer. `isReady` method is basically `timer == 0`

```
    for (Client c : participants) {
        PlayerTargetDomain dom = c.getTarget();
        if (dom.isReady()) {
            if (dom.getSearchDelay() == 0) {
                SharedTargetDomain d;
                if ((d = search(c)) != null) {
                    participants.removeAll(Arrays.asList(d.getFirst(), d.getSecond()));
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                dom.tickSearchDelay();
            }
        }
        else dom.tick();
    }
```

Now the search() method, basically looks for a matching target, and if found it will build `SharedTargetDomain` which contains the current index, and the found target index objects.

If the returned `SharedTargetDomain` instance from `search(Client)` was not null, I will remove both of the objects from the `participants` list using `removeAll()`

Unfortunately, if I remove any of them I will get the following error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at mod.game.TargetManager.execute(TargetManager.java:24)
```

The line 24 is this:

```
for (Client c : participants) {
```

Why am I getting this? I've tried using Iterator for the current index, but I still get the error because I am deleting the other index too, but what does the other one has to do with the current index if I delete it? I am really misunderstanding something.

Thanks!

`Iterator` implementation:

```
    Iterator<Client> itr = participants.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Client c = itr.next();
        if (c != null) {
            PlayerTargetDomain dom = c.getTarget();
            if (dom.isReady()) {
                if (dom.getSearchDelay() == 0) {
                    SharedTargetDomain d;
                    if ((d = search(c)) != null) {
                        participants.remove(d.getSecond());
                        itr.remove();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dom.tickSearchDelay();
                }
            }
            else dom.tick();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your code that you have tried with `Iterator`? `Iterator` works fine to remove the element while iterating.

Comment: It's not the current index that has the problem, ConcurrentModificationExceptions occur when you modify a list that something else is using.  Can you show us the implementation you used with iterators?

Comment: @JonTaylor Added the Iterator implementation, the error shows on itr.remove() line.

Comment: The problem is `participants.remove(d.getSecond());` you can't use `Iterator` in this way. Only `it.remove()` is valid call.

Comment: You can't modify collection in situation when there is an iterator which is used for example to iterate through collection. A collection modification causes this iterator to be broken so that's why you get this exception. Using above form of for loop compiler creates for you an iterator. To solve this you should create the iterator for your own and used it to remove items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you modifying collection while iterating it.

There are at least two solution

1. Use index access. You get a lot of fun handling indexes because element will be shifted after remove.
2. Collect elements that you need to remove and apply all changes after finish iteration, You get a lot of fun always having in mind that element you processing can be already scheduled for deletion.

Comment: go with second option.

Comment: you can use CopyOnWriteArrayList also

Comment: Went with the 2nd option, removed both after the for loop.

Comment: @YSBhai So basically CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList will fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

CopyOnWriteArrayList to avoid this exception